# SQL query - trying to return records that contains results from previous records and the current records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select

so my table (Table A) contains records that shows who an employee reports to.
When a person changes the "Reports To" it will update the Table and display the OLD and NEW value. I am struggling to write a SQL query to return the Previous employer alongside the new employer.

Table A

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------  
ID    |Date                           |Employee |Reports To  |Command
-----------------------------------------------------------------------   
1     |2020-05-05 09:32:56.193        |EMP0        |EMP1      OLD
-----------------------------------------------------------------------   
2     |2020-05-05 09:39:56.193        |EMP0        |EMP2      NEW
-----------------------------------------------------------------------   
3     |2020-05-05 11:32:56.193        |EMP0        |EMP2      OLD
-----------------------------------------------------------------------   
4     |2020-05-05 11:38:56.193        |EMP0        |EMP3      NEW
-----------------------------------------------------------------------   
5     |2020-05-05 19:32:56.193        |EMP0        |EMP3      OLD
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------   
6     |2020-05-05 19:35:56.193        |EMP0        |EMP2      NEW
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Results I would like to return:

```
------------------------------------------------------------   
ID    |Employee |Currently Reports To |Previously Reported To
-------------------------------------------------------------  
1      EMP0         EMP2               EMP1  
-------------------------------------------------------------  
2      EMP0         EMP3               EMP2      
-------------------------------------------------------------
3      EMP0         EMP2               EMP3      
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

SQL Query I have tried:

````
SELECT Employee, tb1.[Reports To] FROM Table A tb1 JOIN Table A tb2
ON tb1.Employee =tb2.Employee AND tb1.Reports To <> tb2.Reports To
AND tb2.Command = 'OLD'
WHERE tb1.Command = 'NEW'```
````

Comment: And what is the problem with this query ? (Except the select part that should be ```SELECT tb1.ID, tb1,Employee, tb1.[Reports To] , tb2.[Reports To] ```)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If "old" and "new" records properly interleave, you can just use `lead()` or `lag()`:

```
select
    employee,
    reports_to     as currently_reports_to,
    lag_reports_to as previously_reported_to
from (
    select t.*, lag(reports_to) over(partition by employee order by date, id) lag_reports_to
    from mytable t
) t
where command = 'NEW'
```

Comment: @GMB . . . I think your code would be easier to read if you used `as` for column aliases.  I am also hesitant about this solution because the timestamps are exactly the same.  That means the results are unstable.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: thanks. I added a second sorting criteria.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `apply` :

```
select row_number() over (order by t.date) as id,
       t.employee, t.reportsto as CurrentlyReportsTo, t1.reportsto as PreviouslyReportsTo
from table t cross apply
     ( select top (1) t1.reportsto
       from tab;e t1
       where t1.employee = t.employee and t1.command = 'OLD' and t1.date <= t.date
       order by t1.date desc
     ) t1
where t.command = 'NEW';
```

Answer (score 0):

Your rows have exactly the same time stamps.  That allow you to use aggregation as well:

```
select employee,
       max(case when command = 'NEW' then reports_to end) as current_reports_to,
       max(case when command = 'OLD' then reports_to end) as previously_reports_to
from t
group by employee, timestamp;
```